# Where is this python object.text method comming from?

Tags: python, django, selenium, tdd

In my learning lessons I saw this code:

```
def check_for_row_in_list_table(self, row_text):
    table = self.browser.find_element_by_id('id_list_table')
    rows = table.find_elements_by_tag_name('tr')
    self.assertIn(row_text, [row.text for row in rows])
```

Now Iam wondering where this text method in the last line for row is comming from?? What type is row?

Comment: Your example provides very little context for people to help you. It could be anybody's code that gives you this. You need to read the code base and trace where does the each variable comes from and read the documentation for the tools.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`find_elements_by_tag_name()` method returns a list of [`WebElement` objects](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/api.html#module-selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement), `row` is a `WebElement` object, [`.text`](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/api.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement.text) is it's property.

Comment: Ah thanks a lot for the link. I was looking for that site